# Short form to return method result if condition passed

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there's any pythonic or short-form method to achieve the following:

```
    error_response = self.check_conditions(request)
    # If we have an error response, return it, otherwise continue as normal.
    if error_response:
        return error_response
```

Something like:

```
(return self.check_conditions(request)) or pass
```

Alternatively, is it possible for a function to return the calling method, such as:

```
self.check_conditions(request)

def check_conditions(self, request):
    error_response = do_stuff()
    if error_response:
        return_parent error_response
```

I get the feeling the second concept is breaking a ton of programming laws to prevent chaos and the apocalypse, just a thought though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no short form for a conditional `return`.

But, to get to the second part of your question:

There are exceptions in Python. You can write something like this:

```
class MyErrorResponse(Exception): pass

class MyClass:
    ...
    def check_conditions(self, request):
        error_response = do_stuff()
        if error_response:
            raise MyErrorResponse(error_response)

    def do_the_main_stuff():
        try:
            self.check_conditions()
            ...
        except MyErrorResponse as e:
            return e.args[0]
```

Comment: Yeah I guess this is what I was expecting, just hoping there was a gap in my knowledge. It seems like a very common structure so I had a glimmer of hope :) Using Exceptions here make sense too of course.

Comment: I once wondered about that too :) At least you can collapse the if-return blocks into one line: `if error_response: return error_response`. I think one of the main reasons it doesn't exist is that nobody could think of a syntax for this case yet that looks good, doesn't introduce new keywords and doesn't violate too much of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Answer (score 1):

That depends a lot on what `check_conditions` does under the hood. It's likely that you can move error handling down a level of abstraction and handle things directly:

Compare:

```
error = False

def foo(request):
    global error
    try:
        result = do_something_with(request)
    except SomeWellDefinedError:
        error = True

def check_conditions(request):
    foo(request)
    return error

def main():
    error_response = check_conditions(some_request)
    if error_response:
        # freak out!
```

With

```
def foo(request):
    try:
        result = do_something_with(request)
    except SomeWellDefinedError:
        # you can try to handle the error here, or...
        raise  # uh oh!

def main():
    try:
        foo(some_request)
    except SomeWellDefinedError:
        # handle the error here, instead!
```